# Not insert in database JSON string when data value is null

Tags: php, json

I'm working with JSON string (array data) coming from AJAX.

Until now, it's working. But last few days, I receive  apparently from Ukraine (ip analyse) JSON array with 'data:null'.

Is it possible to code a condition before insert in database with an error message?

Currently I am checking with:

```
if($item[0]['data1'] !=Null || $item[0]['data1'] !='') 
{ insert request }
```

and the same for the other array data

Is it correct ?

Comment: You should validate your input regardless where it comes from. And to get a meaningful answer to your question, you need to post the code you are using.

Comment: if($item[0]['data1'] !=Null || $item[0]['data1'] !='') and the same for the others array data { insert request  } ?
Is it correct ? Thanks

Comment: Why are you asking? Supply yourself with bad data and check if your code catches it or not. -1 for lack of effort, you could and SHOULD solve this on your own, you know enough.